# How to find the photon view id on unity and store it on a script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I'm creating my first multiplayer game using photon and I don't know how to find the photon view id on unity and store it on a script. Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cmon, do any effort before asking... It's literally in the first line of documentation...

https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_photon_view.html

```
GetComponent<PhotonView>().viewId;
```